# java classes and database queries

Tags: java, database, dao

Can someone please explain the best way to solve this problem.

Suppose I have three classes

1.Person

2.Venue

3.Vehicle

I have a DAO method that needs to return some or all of these attributes from each of the classes after doing a query.

How do I accomplish this ? It seems very wrong to make a class PersonVenueVehicle and return that as an object to get the instance field, values.

I was taught that the database entities must be reflected by classes, if this is case how is it implemented in such a situation

Comment: How do they relate to one another?

Comment: Do you already have the database behind it or only trying to establish it?

Comment: Create a new object that holds those types, it does not have to be an entity if it is not persisted.

Comment: Based on your wording in the question and the question itself I'd say you should start with reading a book or finding and learning some tutorials over the web about ORM (object relational mapping).

Comment: I have a database behind it. I am using servlet and jsp with tomct/ mysql . No frameworks, just my own MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Spring-ish solution.  Besides your three classes, you can have 3 DAO classes, one for each.  But you have a task to perform; I don't know what it is; I'm just going to guess.

Suppose you are running a taxi service; `Person`s schedule through your company taxis to pick them up at a `Venue`, and you send them a `Vehicle`.  Call this combination a `Trip`, and now you want a class that manages `Trip`s in the database.  Create a class called `TripService`. This should use your `PersonDao`, your `VenueDao`, and your `VehicleDao` to create if necessary person and venue records in the database, and should do the calculations needed to choose which `Vehicle` to use. When it does, it should use a new `TripDao` to persist a new `Trip` object.  But, as the organizer, it should create and vend the database connection to all the DAOs, and should do the commit or rollback itself.

If you're using Hibernate or JPA, your classes could be modified.  But the principle is the same.  Even if I have your motivation wrong, you can write a service that coordinates the three DAOs and vends the connection. It can, if it has to, use the connection itself to do a SELECT on the three tables JOINed together.

You lose much of the benefits of a database if the only statements you write are simple SELECTs and UPDATEs and INSERTs

Comment: I'm using neither with one DAO. Not my idea , just the requirements I got

Comment: One DAO for all three business classes?  How can *that* be a requirement? I'd split your one DAO into three, despite that requirement. Classes should have a single purpose. It won't hurt anything, and it will improve your program.

Comment: You need a more senior programmer to educate management.  *Sigh*.  You should take that problem to the Programmers SO site.